# Route anchor tag helper to a specific controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have an application having `MVC` controllers, `Api`controllers with same names. I want the `a` tag helper inside my views to route to `MVC` controllers instead of `Api` controllers. Here is my `Startup` class

```
 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "areas",
       pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
               pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

and the BasiApiController (parent controller for all API controllers)

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase{...}
```

whenever I use `<a asp-controller='persons'>People directory</a>` the link is `api/persons/index` instead of `/persons/index`.

How to force the a tag helper to route to a specific namespace or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, You have to decide to you need api prefix or not. If not then remove [ApiController] from your base class. I don't see what do you need it for. And change the base controller route, by removing api, if you don't want your routes to start from "api".

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase{...}
```

If you want some controllers keep api prefix, but some not, you have to mark them by special route attributes. Computer doesn't know what is in your mind.

```
public class PersonsController : BaseApiController 
.....
[Route("~/Persons")]
[Route("~/Persons/Index")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
.....
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Serge but I have thousands of actions and I don't to refactor the code actually. can I you provide me with an universal solution? a global one